# Objective-C "Expression result unused"

Tags: boolean, objective-c-2.0

I have declared a BOOL and am flipping it's value when a user presses a button.

I do so like this: `!self.isEditing;`, but XCode warns me "Expression result unused"

Can this cause problems? Should I instead do: `self.isEditing = !self.isEditing;`?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `!self.isEditing`, you're not actually changing the value of `self.isEditing`. So, yeah, you should use `self.isEditing = !self.isEditing`.